# recovery of package.json is that possible for angular projects?

Tags: angular, package.json

For an agnular project is there a tool or script that can reconstruct package.json based upon a backup of modules folder ?
ea traverse the dependencies sum it all up and create the package.json file, reverse engineered.

A little aged server ran fine for years no one took care about it (and so it got outdated) Now it seems it won't update conflicts deep dependencies somehow its current package.json file, isn't the real deal or so. npm install does not compile. I can return to a backup but am not able to update due to deep level dependencies. I'm therefor not even sure what was actually active in terms of versions. (doubting its package.json content).